# User entered data is not storing in component's variable Angular Reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Hello I am using Angular reactive forms, I have used FormArray to add form controls dynamically. I am using ngModel directive to store user entered data in components variable. but it not storing it in components variable. my code is:

```
<form [formGroup]="reviewForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="example-label">
    <span class='block'>    
          <span *ngIf="selectedForm">
                  <h2 class="example-heading">{{displayForm}} </h2>
          </span>
    <div formArrayName="controlArray">
      <div *ngFor="let control of reviewForm.get('controlArray').controls; let i = index">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td> <span *ngIf="control.value.controlType == 'text'">
          <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="{{control.value.placeholder}}" 
            ([ngModel])="control.value.value" > <!--user entered data is not storing in control.value.value -->
          </md-form-field>  
      </span></td>

          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!reviewForm.valid">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the component class code:

```
export class FormListComponent {

  formsDb: FormData[];
  selectedForm: FormData;
  displayForm: String;
  test: String;
  reviewForm = new FormGroup({
    'controlArray': new FormArray([])
  });
  constructor(public formService: FormService, public authGuardService: AuthGuardService) {
    console.log('form-list is logged in 0528', this.authGuardService.authService.isLoggedIn);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reviewForm = new FormGroup({
      'controlArray': new FormArray([
      ])
    });
    this.showDefaultForm();
  }



  addForm() {
    this.displayForm = this.selectedForm.formName;
    this.reviewForm.setControl('controlArray', new FormArray([]));  //to reset FormArray               
    console.log('selected form 0528', this.selectedForm);
    for (let control of this.selectedForm.controlsArr) {
      const myControl: Control = new Control(control.controlType, control.label, control.required,
        control.placeholder, control.options);

      var controlArg: FormControl;
      if (control.required)
        controlArg = new FormControl(myControl, Validators.required);
      else
        controlArg = new FormControl(myControl);

      (<FormArray>this.reviewForm.get('controlArray')).push(controlArg);
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('submitted form 0528', this.reviewForm);
  }
}
```

Here is my Control class, I pass its object to FormControl constructor:

```
export class Control{  
    constructor(public controlType?:string, public label?:string, public required?:boolean ,public placeholder?:string, 
      public options?:string[], public value?:string){  }
  }
```

to check whether user entered data is stored in component's variable I logged my FormGroup variable i.e. reviewForm in this case. No data is saved in it. Please help, Thanks

Comment: Please provide the component source. You are mixing reactive and template driven form, it's not a good idea.

Comment: Component source is added in the question, Actually I am new in Angular.

Comment: Please help, how do I save user entered data in component's variable. @JEY

Comment: Try [(ngModel)] instead of ([ngModel])

Comment: is it correct syntactically, I didn't seen this anywhere

Comment: ([ngModel])="control.value.value" > <!--user entered data is not storing in control.value.value -->

Comment: not working either

Comment: @JEY You said I'm mixing reactive and template driven form, now I've removed ngModel in form from my code. is it OK now? and please also tell how to read input of my form. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest not using `ngModel` in reactive forms. Utilize the form controls instead for your reactive form, so remove `value` and `[(ngModel)]`. Here's a simplified version of your code for you to get the idea. Build the form, and if you are getting some default values, iterate that array and push formgroups to your formArray:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.reviewForm = fb.group({
    controlArray: fb.array([])
  })
  let controlArr = this.reviewForm.controls.controlArray as FormArray
  // arr contains your default values
  this.arr.forEach(x => {
    controlArr.push(fb.group({
      controlType: [x.controlType],
      value: [x.value]
    }))
  })
}
```

Then in your template, switch to using `formControlName` for your controls, and also add `formGroupName` for each formgroup in your FormArray:

```html
<div formArrayName="controlArray">
  <!-- add formGroupName -->
  <div *ngFor="let control of reviewForm.get('controlArray').controls; 
               let i = index" 
               [formGroupName]="i">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> 
          <span *ngIf="control.value.controlType == 'text'">
            <div class="example-full-width">
              <input type="text" formControlName="value">
             </div>  
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpqpxl?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm getting an error by applying this solution, The error says: "Cannot find control with path". I think it is giving error because "value" is not the control name, I made a class of control with the required attributes. and while creating FormControl I pass my control class object as its first parameter.

Comment: I have added my Control class in question, Please help.

Comment: @WaleedShahzaib Well what I provided was just a sample, instead of `value` just apply your own form control names in the looping where you set  the form groups to form array.

Comment: I tried it as well but it is not working either.  I tried control.value.value(Control class attribute where I want to store entered data.) as formControlName,

Comment: in Angular form to align label and property, If we don't use table for alignment, is there another way to do this? Sorry for asking it here. I didn't find another way to ask. @AJT_82

Comment: @WaleedShahzaib I'm sorry, not exactly understanding your question, could you elaborate?

Comment: please tell, what makes an Angular component a parent component, as far as I know if we use a component's directive in other component template makes other component parent. Right? Furthermore, if we navigate to a component using routerLink in button element, Does this also makes the other component a parent component? Sorry for asking it here, I did not know any other platform to ask. @AJT_82

Comment: a parent component can be when it has the child selector in parent like `<child></child>` also it can be a parent when you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside parent. When it comes to component communication (if that is behind this question) it means that when you have the child selector inside parent you can use `@Input` and `@Output`, whereas you cannot use that when child is behind a router-outlet. In that case you need to use service. Hopefully it helps :)